# Anchor links in page not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, anchor

The site is http://differenzaus.com/. Try any of the buttons on the page (e.g., the one in the header "Work With Us," which is supposed to link to the "Contact" form). The button appears active but when you click on it nothing happens. This wasn't a problem prior to last night. I'd fixed a close event on the slidebar menu, and after that the anchor/targets weren't working.

Any tips? The source code is all available via view source.

Comment: Code, post code.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're catching the click event that would allow the buttons to work, and using it exclusively to collapse the sidebar menu:

```
// Toggle main menu
    $( '[canvas]' ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        controller.close( 'menuMain' );
    } );
```

Try removing the calls to `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`, or wrap the event hander in an if statement that checks whether the sidebar is already open.

Answer (score 0):

You added `#` to all of your `href` attributes. 
If you hover over your buttons you will get ex. `#contact`.

Take a look in your code if you insert `#`.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to some Javascript in there. The links are correct, and so are the section IDs. If you deactivate Javascript completely, the links work. Probably some scolling script. Deactivate the scripts one by one to find it and then try to find the error in the script.